# Find outlier using z score

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to create a function in R. The function should find outliers from a matrix using z score. The function should have two arguments as input (x which is a matrix and zs which is an integer). For each raw of the matrix, the function should calculate the zscore for each element and if zscore is bigger than `zs` or smaller than `-zs`, then the function should print that element. I know that I can use:

```
z<- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)   or  z<- scale(x)
```

for the calculations of z score but as I am a beginner in programming, I find it difficult to solve the problem because of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this code:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)
temp <- abs(apply(mat, 1, scale))
mat[temp > 2]
### [1]  1.9803999  0.2670988 -1.2765922
```

I took 2 standard deviations for your Z limit. 
First i create a random matrix.
Then i then scale it row by row (the '1' argument of the apply function)
I apply 'abs' to avoid having to test on both sides (< and >), since the test is symetric
Eventually it gives you the outlier values. But you also might want to see where they are, just do:

```
image(temp > 2)
```

[image]

EDIT: If you need it as a function inputting x and zs, i wrapped it:

```
outliers = function(x, zs) {
  temp <- abs(apply(x, 1, scale))
  return(x[temp > zs])
}

### > outliers(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10), 2)
### [1]  1.9803999  0.2670988 -1.2765922
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for your instant help. What i need is that user should input x (matrix) and zs and the function should return the outliers (zscore>zs or zscore< -zs). Thanks

Comment: @Alan What do you mean "should return the outliers"? You want a list of their values or you want their position row/column, or  maybe just the initial matrix with TRUE/FALSE? Please specify

Comment: A list of their values. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Let me check that I understood your code right. We create the function outliers with input x and zs. We create a variable temp which calculates the absolute value of z score for each row of x. Then our function returns the values of the zscores that are bigger of zs. Right? In your example, x is a matrix with 100 random values and 10 columns. zs=2. Right? Then since it must return values above zs, why the return is 1.9803999  0.2670988 -1.2765922? Thanks

Comment: you got it right. For the "why the return values are not above 2" question, it's just because of the scaling: don't forget that the outliers are the values in the initial matrix, not the scaled matrix!

Comment: no problem. If one one the answers solves your problem, please accept it or upvote it, so other people can benefit from it. Rgds.

Comment: I accepted the answer but unfortunately I cannot upvote it because I  don't have 15 reputation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
myfun <- function(x, zs) { 
    x1 <- apply(x, 1, scale)
    x2 <- (abs(x1) - abs(zs)) > 0
    return(x * x2)
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your help. so i guess user can input x (matrix) and zs. then x1 takes each row and scales the elements ??? then if x1 (zscore) - zs>0 then why it returns x*x2? Also, so for asking, i know that is a silly question, but how i insert the data? myfun(what i should include)? Thanks

Comment: Cellwise multiplication by a True/False matrix (x2) results in a matrix that has same dimension as original matrix `x`, with all values of the original matrix that meet the "outlier" criteria. You could use this function by running `outliers <- myfun(x=yourmatrix, zs=yourz)` where `your` represents whatever input values you want to use.